# What command-line options are available for Ubuntu One?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-one-windows

Is there a place I can see the Command Line Switches for Ubuntu One? At the moment, I only know of two: '--minimized' and '--with-icon'. They were included in the shortcut when Ubuntu One installed on my Windows machine.

I mainly need to know if there is one to start the Ubuntu One file sync from the Command Line so I can build a custom scheduler. I don't think the difference in the operating systems matter because all commands thus far are controlled through the 'ubuntuone-control-panel-qt' executable. I could be mistaken though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the syncdaemon:

**`u1sdtool [OPTION]... [ARGS]`**

```
  u1sdtool [OPTION]... [ARGS]
   u1sdtool --wait
   u1sdtool --accept-share=SHARE_ID
   u1sdtool --reject-share=SHARE_ID
   u1sdtool --list-shares
   u1sdtool --refresh-shares
   u1sdtool --offer-share PATH USER SHARE_NAME ACCESS_LEVEL
   u1sdtool --list-shared
   u1sdtool --create-folder=PATH
   u1sdtool --delete-folder=FOLDER_ID
   u1sdtool --list-folders
   u1sdtool --subscribe-folder=FOLDER_ID
   u1sdtool --unsubscribe-folder=FOLDER_ID
   u1sdtool --refresh-volumes
   u1sdtool --rescan-from-scratch=VOLUME_ID
   u1sdtool --info=PATH
   u1sdtool --list-dirty-nodes
   u1sdtool --current-transfers
   u1sdtool --quit
   u1sdtool --connect
   u1sdtool --disconnect
   u1sdtool --status
   u1sdtool --waiting
   u1sdtool --waiting-metadata
   u1sdtool --waiting-content
   u1sdtool --start
```

OPTIONS

```
   --wait Wait until ubuntuone-syncdaemon reachs nirvana

   --accept-share=SHARE_ID
          Accept the share with the specified id

          SHARE_ID
                 The share id, as returned by --list-shares

   --reject-share=SHARE_ID
          Reject the share with the specified id

          SHARE_ID
                 The share id, as returned by --list-shares

   --list-shares
          Get the list of shares

   --refresh-shares
          request a refresh of the list of shares to the server

   --offer-share=PATH USER SHARE_NAME ACCESS_LEVEL
          share PATH to USER.

          PATH   A path of a  directory  or  file  managed  by  ubuntuone-
                 syncdaemon (can't be a path inside a Share)

          USER   The  (short)  username,  that  this  share is going to be
                 offered

          SHARE_NAME
                 The share name, as it's going to be offered to USER

          ACCESS_LEVEL
                 The acces level of USER to this share, can be: "View"  or
                 "Modify"

   --list-shared
          List the shared paths/shares offered.

   --create-folder=PATH
          Create user defined folder in the specified path

          PATH   The  path  of  a  directory  to  be managed by ubuntuone-
                 syncdaemon

   --delete-folder=FOLDER_ID
          Delete user defined folder identified by FOLDER_ID

          FOLDER_ID
                 The folder id, as returned by --list-folders

   --list-folders
          List all the user defined folders

   --subscribe-folder=FOLDER_ID
          Subscribe to the user defined folder specified by FOLDER_ID

          FOLDER_ID
                 The folder id, as returned by --list-folders

   --unsubscribe-folder=FOLDER_ID
          Unsubscribe from the user defined folder specified by FOLDER_ID

          FOLDER_ID
                 The folder id, as returned by --list-folders

   --refresh-volumes
          Request a refresh of the list of volumes to the server

   --rescan-from-scratch=VOLUME_ID
          Request a rescan from scratch for a volume.

          VOLUME_ID
                 The volume id, as returned by --list-folders  or  --list-
                 shares

   --info=PATH
          Request the metadata of PATH

          PATH   A  path  of  a  directory  or  file managed by ubuntuone-
                 syncdaemon

   --list-dirty-nodes
          Show the list of nodes marked as 'dirty'

   --current-transfers
          Show the current uploads and downloads

   --quit Shutdown ubuntuone-syncdaemon

   --connect
          Connect the syncdaemon

   --disconnect
          Disconnect the syncdaemon

   --status
          Get the current status of syncdaemon

   --waiting
          Get the operations being executed.

   --waiting-metadata
          Get the waiting metadata list (NOTE: This option  is  deprecated
          and will go away shortly)

   --waiting-content
          Get  the  waiting  content list (NOTE: This option is deprecated
          and will go away shortly)

          SHARE_ID
                 The share id, as returned by --waiting

          NODE_ID
                 The node id, as returned by --waiting

   --free-space=VOLUME_ID
          Get the free space for a volume.

          VOLUME_ID
                 The volume id, as returned by --list-folders  or  --list-
                 shares

   --start
          Start syncdaemon if it's not running
```

*Please note that on Windows,* `ubuntuone-control-panel-qt.exe` *should be fully running before executing* `u1sdtool.exe`.

<sub>Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/u1sdtool.1.html</sub>

Comment: Thank you @ObsessiveFOSS. The '--connect' command is definitely the most useful. I will give it a shot and report back.

Comment: It does solve my issue. Thank you very much. It should be noted for the Windows client that you must have "ubuntuone-control-panel-qt.exe" fully running prior to using "u1sdtool.exe".

Comment: @toddimyre I rarely use Windows, so sorry for that omission.

Comment: It's okay. I bounce between two different Windows systems, two different Ubuntu systems, and a Mac system (at work), so I know all about varying differences between systems.

Comment: Can you please note the Windows comment in your answer, and also check that the Precise manpage shows no additional/changed switches from Lucid? Thanks, great answer.

Comment: @izx Thanks for the heads-up! I did notice that there were new switches, so I performed the necessary edits, and included the comment about running on Windows.